# My android application is showing Incompatible for Android 4.4.4 Moto E In Play Store

Tags: android

My android application is showing Incompatible for Android 4.4.4 Moto E in Google play store,

I tried many ways,  How do i resolve this issue. Can you please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ru using Google-Maps in your application..?

Comment: Yes Rajesh i am using Google maps in my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your Using Google-Maps , then for supporting Moto E you have remove

this ,

```
 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

from your `Manifest` file..

Moto E not supporting OpenGL ES version 2 i think .. i had the same problem i removed above code then it started supporting..

or simple change `android:required="false"`

### Incompatible Problems

This type of problems can occur based on the App `Permissions`, you might be using Some `Permissions` which that device is `Not Supporting` or `Not Available` on that `Device`.

Suppose if your App is supporting for `Tablets`, then your app should not use `PHONE` `Permissions` in your App, if you use `PHONE Permissions` for tablets then your app will be `Incompatible` for such kind of `Tablets` which don't have `PHONE` Feature..

Hope this info Helps you in future..

Comment: Thank you Rajesh, Hope it will work. Let me check. Thanks allot

Comment: ok...update you app to playstore and check ... don't forget for update your versionCode and VersionName in your Manifest..

Comment: No need to remove that entry from manifest. Simply change `android:required="true"` with `android:required="false"`

Comment: @RajeshMikkilineni I am also using Maps, and after changing to <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="false"/>, still its not compatible. What I felt is due to lollipop permission format, I have used hasPermission permission method, which do check for basic permissions required for lollipop but also add feature in shadow mode, which was not in manifest but when i encrypted the apk with the tool to get permission list i got that feature line there, now i dont know how to remove it..

Answer (score 0):

This problem raised to me, I just added layouts for various screen sizes and it works and supported my phone. Hope it help. Have a nice day.

Comment: could you elaborate this, because I cant figure out what layout is missing for me.