# App Shows In-Compatible with Moto E from Google Store

Tags: java, android, android-layout, google-play-services

We have uploaded screenshots, and following is the different part of manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />


<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

This is not working on some tablets as well. I can provide more information on this. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have the same issue. I thinks its due to the autofocus feature. Moto E's camera has a fixed focus. Try changing it to required=false.

Comment: @GunnerFan I tried all of the above but still the same, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Some tablets might not have camera? Try adding

```
android:required="false"
```

to camera & autofocus.

2) Also, another reason might be that Open GL isn't supported by all devices (Specially in case of Moto E).
so try changing to

```
android:required="false"
```

in

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

Moto E has fixed camera focus & apparently doesn't support OpenGL 2.

Ref.:
[App incompatible with Moto E in Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078037/my-android-application-is-showing-incompatible-for-android-4-4-4-moto-e-in-play)

If anyone else has faced similar issues, please share your research!

Comment: Camera focus was indeed the problem. Thanks!!