# Application showing incompatible for MOTO E in play store

Tags: android, android-permissions

My application showing incompatible on play store for MOTO E device, I have not used any .

My permission code :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: have you looked at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078037/my-android-application-is-showing-incompatible-for-android-4-4-4-moto-e-in-play) your probably just missing the "uses-feature"

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the incompatibility is probably a too low SDK version on the phone. Check the `minSdkVersion` (you will find that in the `build.gradle` of the module if you are using Android Studio/IntelliJ.

Comment: my minsdk version is 14 and MOTO E is of 18 or 19 still  I am getting this.